# No module named defaults Django-Simple-Friends

Tags: django, django-urls

I installed the django-simple-friends app and am now getting the error message:
 `No module named defaults`
I think I know the issue put am not sure how to resolve it.

I am running django 1.6 and in Django 1.6 "`from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url`" was replaced with "`from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include`".

From what I can tell the django-simple-friends url.py has: `from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url`

When I remove the `url(r'^friends/', include('friends.urls')),` link in the root url.py I can get the error to go away but obviously I cannot use the app.

In django-simple-friends url.py if I replaced `from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url` with `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include` would this resolve my issue?

If so how do I get to the django-simple-friends url.py file? I did a pip install django-simple-friends and I cannot see the django-simple-friend directory files. (plus I am fairly new to Django/programming so am not sure even where to look)

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work when you replace `django.conf.urls.defaults` with `django.conf.urls`, you can **send a pull request to the upstream** like [this](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/pull/36) then wait the upstream upgrades.

Or you can modify the package yourself, and **install your modified version** using pip, it provides [a lot of ways to install](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#examples).

Answer (score 0):

Using `django.conf.urls` instead of `django.conf.usrls.defualt` will work. `defaults` model has been dropped in Django-1.6.

To avoid model import problems install Django-1.5 and run the original code.